# BroadcastReceiver makes crash my app and my service in OnReceive() method

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, service, xamarin.android, broadcastreceiver

I implemented an android service which allows to register sms. My service is started from the start of the app and it's restarted when I kill the app (by swiping). The problem occured when the app received a sms: the app and the service crashed without any exception. The problem is only available for the android version < 8.0.

When the app crashed it doesn't fired to service's or MainActivity's OnDestroy() nor to OnTaskRemoved. I could do whatever inside the OnReceive method the problem is still there, when the app finished the process, the app and the service stopped.

Here is the OnReceive method

```cs
public override async void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
   //start service
   if (intent.Action.Equals(SERVICE_ACTION))
   {
      if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
      {
        context.StartForegroundService(new Intent(context, typeof(BackgroundService)));

      }
      else
      {
         var intentTmp = new Intent(context, typeof(BackgroundService));
         context.StartService(intentTmp);
      }
  }
  //receive sms
  else if (intent.Action.Equals(SMS_ACTION))
  {
      var result = GoAsync();
      await ReceiveSMSBroadcast(intent);
      result.Finish();
  }
}

//Sms processing
    private async Task ReceiveSMSBroadcast(Intent intent)
        {
            var transmitter = "";
            var message = "";
            long timestamp = 0;

            //A mapping from String values : Retrieves a map of extended data from the intent.
            Bundle bundle = intent.Extras;

            if (bundle != null)
            {
                if (intent.HasExtra("pdus"))
                {
                    //Retrieve sms message
                    var smsArray = (Java.Lang.Object[])bundle.Get("pdus");

                    SmsMessage[] smsMessages = Telephony.Sms.Intents.GetMessagesFromIntent(intent);

                    foreach (var smsItem in smsMessages)
                    {
                        transmitter = smsItem.OriginatingAddress;
                        message = smsItem.MessageBody;
                        timestamp = smsItem.TimestampMillis / 1000;

                        var servers = await _serverRepository.ReadAll();

                        foreach (var server in servers)
                        {
                            foreach (var phone in server.PhoneNumbersBlob)
                            {
                                if (phone.Equals(transmitter))
                                {
                                    await CreateAlarm(server, message, timestamp);
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The app and the service should still working after the sms processing

Comment: When it crashes there are logcat messages telling you why the crash happened (called the stacktrace). Post that here. Often with background services, you need to filter through the logcat output.

Comment: have you registered your `BroadcastReceiver` in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: There is only this error on the android device log: **Force stopping service ServiceRecord{2a7cb7d u0 com.topkapi_scada.TopAstreinte/md52e434a1c21fff364f7c20f4241be5887.BackgroundService}**

Comment: @AmjadAlwareh I registered on the OnCreate() of the service with **RegisterReceiver()**